# Angular 2: Two backend service calls on success of first service

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services

In my Angular 2 app I have backend service as below.

```
getUserInterests() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/test/selections').map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

After calling this service I want to call another service on success of previous one.

**2nd service**

```
let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('access_token', localStorage.getItem('access_token'));
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/user/selections', { search: params }).map((res: Response) => res.json());
```

These two services separately return two JSON Arrays. Then I need to do some login with these two arrays.

**EDITED**

**service.ts**

```
getUserInterests() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/test/selections').map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

getSavedSelections() {
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('access_token', localStorage.getItem('access_token'));
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/interest/user/selections', { search: params }).map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

getSelectionList() {
    var obs = this.getUserInterests().flatMap(
        (interests) => {
            return Observable.forkJoin([
                Observable.of(interests),
                this.getSavedSelections()
            ]);
        }
    );
    return obs;
}
```

Then I am using following in my other ts file to call the service.

```
export class InterestsComponent {
  private interests;
  private saved_interests;
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.dataService.getSelectionList().subscribe(
        (result) => {
            var interests = result[0];
            var selections = result[1];
        }
    );
  }
}
```

But this give following error on console log.

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: this.dataService.getSelectionList is not a function
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to leverage the `flatMap` operator to call one request after the previous one completed:

```
this.service.getUserInterests().flatMap(
  (interests) => {
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('access_token', localStorage.getItem('access_token'));
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/user/selections', {
      search: params
    }).map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
);
```

When subscribing to this data flow, you will only receive the result of the last request.

You could use the `Observable.forkJoin` method to return both. Here is a sample:

```
var obs = this.service.getUserInterests().flatMap(
  (interests) => {
    return Observable.forkJoin([
      Observable.of(interests),
      this.service.getUserSelections()
    ]);
  }
);

obs.subscribe(
  (result) => {
    var interests = result[0];
    var selections = result[1];
  }
);
```

Comment: what is interests?

Comment: How can I get responses of two services?

Comment: `interests` corresponds to the result of the first request.

Comment: I updated my answer to describe how to get the result of the two requests in the subscribe callback...

Comment: If you need both response contents, yes ;-)

Comment: Hi Thierry, could you plz check on EDITED question. I tried what you said. But still i cannot make it right

Comment: If you display the dataService instance in console (with `console.log(this.dataService);`) what can you see? Is there this method?

Comment: it prints **DataService {http: Http}**

Comment: Can you expand its content (properties and methods)?

Comment: Now it's working. I think it might not compiled properly

Comment: any plunker with this?