# Multiple Observable subscription

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, rxjs, observable, angularfire2

I need to subscribe multiple times in order to get the right data fro my NoSQL database. In order to fetch user list of specific project, I do this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    //Subscription 1 (Service): Get project data
    this.projectService.getCurrentproject().take(1).subscribe(projectData => {
        console.log('Got project data.');
        //Subscription 2: Get project user IDS
        this.af.database.list('/project_roles/'+projectData.$key)
            .subscribe((userMeta) => {
                });
            });
}
```

- As you can see, a subscription, inside a subscription, inside a subscription.. And each subscription depends on the previous one reslt.
- Subscription 3 and 4 can be parallel.

The code works well, but am I missing something or this is how I suppose working with multiple subscription that the result of the previous one depends the next?

**Update**: There seem a problem with Subscription #2. The subscription is not yet complete but I start iterating over the list, which give me a double user list!

Comment: Did you check the `flatMap` operator? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36712659/angular-2-two-backend-service-calls-on-success-of-first-service/36712707#36712707

Comment: Not sure what's the difference between what I did and `flatMap`, or how to use it with my 4 subscriptions |:

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.projectService.getCurrentproject().take(1)
        .flatMap(projectData => {
            return this.af.database.list('/project_roles/'+projectData.$key)
        })
        .flatMap(userMeta => {
            let subs = userMeta.map(projectRole => {
                return Observable.zip([
                    this.af.database.object('/roles/'+projectRole.$value),
                    this.af.database.object('/users/'+projectRole.$key)
                ]).map(([roleData, user]) => {
                    user.role = roleData.$value;
                    return Observable.of(user)
                })
            });
            return Observable.zip(subs)
        })
        .subscribe(users => {
            this.users = users
        })
}
```

Basically I am composing the subscriptions to get a single observable which emits the users array

Comment: Interesting. This is much better organized - but not working. I investigated it and `userMeta` variables is good, but after it nothing is executed (placed console logs everywhere, and they don't show). the merge observables are not executed.

Comment: found an error... fixed it. the map should return Observable.of(user) instead of user. Observable.zip expects observable array

Comment: I really have no idea why, but the code after `map((roleData, user) => {` is not executed at all. that means the `return Observable.of(user)` is never reached. There are no errors btw

Comment: It's ok I've been trying to figure those things out for days. The code is still not executed, but if I change your code and add a subscription `.subscribe(data => { })` after `return Observable.of(user)
                })` it does executed, but `.subscribe(users => {` is not reached

Comment: please try again.. and instead of subscribe do console log before `Observable.of(user)`

Comment: I did console log everywhere, the console log before `Observable.of(user)` is not showing (and the one before `this.users = users;`)

Comment: Yeah I watch any change you make and try it