# Subscribe to multiple Observables (like chaining then() in Promises)

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

My Angular 2 application has 2 methods (`GetCategories()` and `GetCartItems()`) in a service , and both of these methods return `Observable`s.

In order to invoke these two methods one after another from my component, I have written below code:

```
 ngOnInit() 
{
   this.appService.GetCategories().subscribe( (data) => {
       this.appService.categories = data;


       this.appService.GetCartItems().subscribe( {
                                                    next: (data) => { this.appService.cart = data},
                                                    error: (err) => { this.toaster.error('cart==>' + err)}

                                                })

   });       
}
```

Basically, calling `GetCartItems()` from within `subscribe()` of `GetCategories()`, and I feel this is NOT the right approach. This is kind of callback hell.

Any idea on how to implement this in a better way (like chaining `then()` in `Promise`s)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36712659/angular-2-two-backend-service-calls-on-success-of-first-service/36712707#36712707

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like `GetCartItems` doens't depend on `GetCategories`. Then you can use [zip](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-zip):

```
Observable
    .zip(
        this.appService.GetCategories()
        this.appService.GetCartItems()
    )
    .catch(err => this.toaster.error(err))
    .subscribe(([categories, cartItems]) => {
        this.appService.categories = categories;
        this.appService.cart = cartItems;
    });
```

Comment: I think `Observable.combineLatest` is the right choice, not `Observable.zip` (if I understand the problem). Things may have changed in the year since you wrote this. When I use `Observable.zip` without a third argument as in the above case, one of the inputs is undefined, depending on when the subscription happens to fire.

Answer (score 7):

This is most typically done with `concat()`, `concatMap()` or eventually `concatAll()` depending on your usecase and whetrher you need to call both services in order or not.

```
function GetCategories() {
    return Observable.timer(1000).do(() => console.log('GetCategories()'));
}

function GetCartItems() {
    return Observable.timer(1000).do(() => console.log('GetCartItems()'));
}

console.log('start...');

GetCategories()
  .concatMap(() => GetCartItems())
  .subscribe(() => console.log('done'));
```

This prints to console:

```
start...
GetCategories()
GetCartItems()
done
```

Each item is delayed to show these are called in order one after another.

If you don't need to keep the same order you can use `merge()` or `mergeMap()`.

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/wawajob/1/edit

Note that using `zip()` might have undesired behavior. See https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/zip.md