# Subscribe to two responses from two different APIs

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I need to retrieve and use two responses from two different APIs. How can I subscribe to two responses from two different APIs?

this is an example that resembles my code:

```
this.myService1.getResponse1().subscribe( res1 => this.res1 = res1 );  
this.myService2.getResponse2().subscribe( res2 => this.res2 = res2 );

this.myFunction(this.res1, this.res2);
```

Comment: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-combineLatest

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361866/subscribe-to-multiple-observables-in-angular-2

Comment: thx @Muthukumar, it meets my need