# Angular 2 :how to bind four services in a single call

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i have referred [two backend service on a success of the first service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36712659/angular-2-two-backend-service-calls-on-success-of-first-service), its solved my problem for two backend services.but i have three backend services, on the success of first service, second services should call and on the success of second services, third should service call.
please help me.

service.ts

Firstservice

```
gethrdata(param)
   {
    var respone: any;
   let headers = new Headers();
     headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     let authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
     console.log(authToken);
     headers.append('X-auth-Token', authToken)
     return this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/ada/api/v1/client/'+param+'/hrdata', '', {headers} )
      /*.map(res => res.json())*/
      .map((res) => {
      respone = res;
      console.log(respone); 
      return respone; 
      });

   }
```

Secondservice

```
 getflagloa(param)
   {
    var respone: any;
   let headers = new Headers();
     headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     let authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
     console.log(authToken);
     headers.append('X-auth-Token', authToken)
     return this._http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/client/'+param+'/loa', { headers })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map((res) => {
      respone = res;
      console.log(respone); 
      return respone; 
      });

   }
```

Thirdservice

```
 insertloa(param)
   {
    var respone: any;
   let headers = new Headers();
     headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

     let authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
     console.log(authToken);
     headers.append('X-auth-Token', authToken);
    /* let options = new RequestOptions({headers:headers});*/
     return this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/client/'+param+'/loadata', '', {headers} )
      /*.map(res => res.json())*/
      .map((res) => {
      respone = res;
      console.log(respone); 
      return respone; 
      });

   }
```

now how can i call these services on success of prevoius service.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: As said you update the post with your code and this can be done with the help of **zip** operator in **Observables**. Can fix it for u only after your seeing your code

Comment: So chain it with `flatMap` 1 more time?

Comment: please find my code.yes i have tried flatMap one more time.but its not working.

Comment: Maybe try .toPromise()? `async` is deliciously readable.