# How to avoid callback hell with ngrx observables

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx, angular2-observables

I need to get data from redux store to make another api call and the response needs to be saved to the store. How can we avoid `callback` hell in this case.

Following is the code snippet which subscribes to the observable.

*Store*

```
this.user$ = this.store.select('user');
this.dataStore$ = this.store.select('dataStore')
```

*Callback Hell*

```
this.user$.subscribe((user: any) => {
  this.abcService.getData(user.id).subscribe((data:any) => {
    this.data = data;
    this.dataStore$.dispatch(abcAction(data));
  }
}
```

How to avoid this above callbacks. In promise world we could easily chain promises. Since `observables` are not chainable, how do we avoid nested callbacks and what is the best way to write above code. Would like to know how best rxjs operators can be applied.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: Two backend service calls on success of first service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36712659/angular-2-two-backend-service-calls-on-success-of-first-service)

Answer (score 4):

You want to leverage many operators `rxjs` provides. For example, you can re-write the above code as following:

```
this.user$
.flatMap((user: any) => this.abcService.getData(user.id))
.subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.data = data;
    this.dataStore$.dispatch(abcAction(data));    
});
```

You can think of these different operators as your `Promise` `then()`s but more powerful because they can do more.

Comment: Is there any good documentation with examples on all rxjs operators?

Comment: @Wishnu Of course there is. I find this page helpful:  http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#categories-of-operators