# What is the best way to chain observables in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

If I have a service call that relies on the result of another service call what is the best way to chain them?

```js
myService.getStuffFromServer().subscribe(data => {
  let manipulatedData = functionThatManipulatesData(data);
  myService.getMoreStuffFromServer(manipulatedData).subscribe(moreData => {
    doStuffWithMoreData(moreData);
  });
});
```

Is the way I have been doing it but the nesting gets a bit messy sometimes. Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: tried flatmap ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: Two backend service calls on success of first service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36712659/angular-2-two-backend-service-calls-on-success-of-first-service)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments its very simple.

```
myService.getStuffFromServer().
  .map(functionThatManipulatesData)
  .flatMap(myService.getMoreStuffFromServer)
  .subscribe(doStuffWithMoreData);
```

> `map` transforms each element of a stream from one type of data to another. 
>   But if that transformation involves an asynchronous call we use `flatMap`.

Most simple way I can describe and this thinking helped me a lot.

We can use `flatMap` also to add more than one item to the stream. For example , map takes one item and replaces that with new item. What if we want to take one item and add 3 items in its place . For example I want to replace a number with its square and cube too .

```
----1---2---3---
```

to

```
----1---1---1---2---4---8---3---9---27----
```

Then we can use `flatMap`

```
stream.flatMap(num => Observable.of(num, num*num, num*num*num));
```

Now flatMap replaces each element with three new elements. These are two important functionalities of flatmap. 
Hope I confused you enough :)

Comment: This makes sense. Most stuff I have been reading on flatMap just confuses the hell out of me.

Comment: I will add few lines to the answer to confuse you more :P

Comment: You should not answer duplicate questions.

Comment: Yes, we should not. But sometimes things are so confusing in rx, its so helpful if someone can give working answer readily. That's my perspective .

Comment: This answer is so much more concise that the convoluted example this has been marked as a duplicate of.

Comment: not to mention, sometimes some answers are much more contextual with respect to the OP's question. Yes, underlying concepts maybe a duplicate, but why stop people from answering questions that gives valid, working examples and clear, concise explanation?

Comment: @CozyAzure https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled/

Answer (score 0):

For **rxjs 6.x.x** (tested with 6.5.4), we need to add the pipe() function like this:

```
myService.getStuffFromServer()
  .pipe(
    map(functionThatManipulatesData), 
    flatMap(manipulatedData =>
        myService.getMoreStuffFromServer(manipulatedData)))
  .subscribe(moreData => {
    doStuffWithMoreData(moreData);
   });
```

To get it to work correctly.

Comment: That works, but you actually just need one pipe and put both the map and flatMap  inside of it, separated by a comma

Comment: Yep, updating now.

Comment: Great! But now you have one ending bracket too much after the map

Answer (score -6):

```
myService.getStuffFromServer()
  .subscribe(data => {
     let manipulatedData = functionThatManipulatesData(data);
     return myService.getMoreStuffFromServer(manipulatedData);
  })
  .subscribe(moreData => {
     doStuffWithMoreData(moreData);
  });
```

Comment: You can't subscribe to subscription object.