# Angular Observables: Sequence of calls

Tags: angular

I’m sure the answer has to be out there but I can’t quite seem to find the case that I’m looking for.  I’ll explain this in non-angular code in a simplistic made up example.

In any rational language it would look something like this:

```
public Book CreateBook(Book theBook)
{
   //theBook is an object submitted by client code. 
   //it has 2 properties missing, call them “Property1” and
   //“Property2”

   //Property1 is filled in by calling one service
   theBook.Property1 = service1.GetMeMyValue();

   //Property2 is filled in automatically by the second service
   //and the updated value is returned.  Property1 MUST be filled in before
   //this is called.
   theBook = service2.SaveBook(theBook);

   return theBook;
}
```

Angular HTTP calls always return Observables.  I can't find the magic sequence of passing the buck to get this to work.  The closest I can come in Angular speak is:

```
createBook(theBook : Book) : Observable<Book>
{
   return this.http.get("http://service1/someEndpoint")
      .map(item => {
         theBook[“Property1”] = item.json()[“Property1”];

         //something next here or outside?  Outside most likely.
      });
}
```

Anything I try with this returns null/undefined regardless of what I do with the inner values (or any modification I try to the outer return).

I’m sure the solution is quite obvious for anyone used to Angular (which is slightly better than JavaScript’s S&M syntax), but it quite escapes me and I’m hoping someone can nudge me in the right direction.

Comment: This isn't related to Angular per se, it's due to the asynchronous behaviour of javascript and web in general. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call, then for the angular/rxjs version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2

Comment: I've been able to get the value from any single call just fine.  I can see how I can use this value to pass into the next call.  What I can't see is how/what i return at the method level to allow the client to get the result from the inner (2nd) HTTP call.

Comment: If you want to chain observables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36712659/angular-2-two-backend-service-calls-on-success-of-first-service/36712707#36712707

Comment: By the way the Observable in `createBook` method of yours won't work because your map function isn't returning anything.

Comment: I know, that is just where I got stuck. I'd tried returning stuff there as well as the outside.  I'll update the details with a result when I verify one works.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**:

```
createBook(theBook : Book) : Observable<Book>
{
   return this.http.get("http://service1/someEndpoint")
      .flatmap(item => {

         //update Property1 with value from 1st GET
         theBook[“Property1”] = item.json()[“Property1”];

         //now create on 2nd service
         return this.http.post(
           “http://service2/createBook”,
           theBook,
           this.createRequestOptions(token))
           .map(response => response.json());
      });
}
```