# Undefined response in first api call in ionic3

Tags: javascript, angular, api, observable, ionic3

I am trying to implement nested api calls in ionic3

```
submitLoginForm() {
    var username = this.formData.value.username;
    var password = this.formData.value.password;
    var bodyjson;
    var userId;

    this.ApidataService.logincheck(username,password).subscribe(data => {
        this.logindetail = data;
        bodyjson = JSON.parse(this.logindetail._body);
        userId =  bodyjson.user.id;
        if( userId != undefined){
            this.ApidataService.userdata(userId).subscribe(data => {
                this.userInfo = data;
            });
        }
        console.log(userId);
    });
    console.log(this.userInfo);
}
```

Now when I call this function the nested api returns undefined for the first call and then from the second call onwards it returns proper values however when I try to log the argument that is being sent to the api I notice that the correct value is passed each time. I believe that this is due to some synchronization issues but am unable to figure out the issue and the solution for the same.

Comment: instead of `( userId != undefined)` just check like `( userId )`

Comment: You can find the angular version of the duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2. What you are doing is trying to access the response of an async operation synchronously. Javascript doesn't work like that. The link covers the fundemantals of async behaviour of js. If you want to chain your observables, you can check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36712659/angular-2-two-backend-service-calls-on-success-of-first-service/36712707#36712707

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` here.It seems you don't need to retrieve results of both requests hence this should work for you.

```
 import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
 import 'rxjs/add/observable/flatMap';
```

Then:

```
 this.ApidataService.logincheck(username,password).flatMap(
  (data) => {
        this.logindetail = data;
        bodyjson = JSON.parse(this.logindetail._body);
        userId =  bodyjson.user.id;
        if( userId != undefined){
          return this.ApidataService.userdata(userId);
        }else{
          return Observable.empty();
        }
    }).map((res: Response) => res ? res.json() : {})
    .subscribe(data => {
           this.userInfo = data ? data : {};
    });
```

You can read more about [**flatMap here**](https://blog.thoughtram.io/rx/2016/08/01/exploring-rx-operators-flatmap.html)

Comment: **Always** using `forkJoin` is a strong claim in my opinion. There are several other ways to handle this situation. E.g `flatMap/mergeMap`

Comment: Corrected.Thanks for the info @echonax

Comment: No problem. But then again your answer is wrong because the `forkJoin` makes the requests in parallel. In OP's situation 1 async calls request depends on the others' response. So..

Comment: Oh..I didn't see that.I'll see the link which you have a shared.Thanks again :) @echonax

Comment: Can you please see is this correct now? @echonax

Comment: Ehm, no because the return type of the `flatMap` needs to be an `Observable`, you are returning a `Subscription`. You need to subscribe to it at the end. And if `userId == undefined`, this code will blow up.

Comment: Any correction please on above post? @echonax

Comment: I did but the question is a duplicate and duplicate questions shouldn't be answered :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have learned a lot.Yeah..But I posted this (Wrong one) before the tagged `Duplicate`.So no issues I think.Thanks again :) @echonax

Comment: This does not seem to work it says

 error [16:34:53]  typescript: src/pages/login/login.ts, line: 63 
            Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'. 

      L63:   this.ApidataService.logincheck(username,password).flatMap(
      L64:    (data) => {

[16:34:53]  typescript: src/pages/login/login.ts, line: 71 
            Property 'empty' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'. 

      L70:  }else{
      L71:    return Observable.empty();

Comment: You need to import this `import 'rxjs/add/observable/flatMap';`.